# Differentiate a matrix trace in Kalman filter

Tags: matrix-calculus, kalman-filter

I have a problem about differentiating a matrix with trace as

$\frac{d T[KHP]}{dK}$,

where $T$ is the trace operation, K, H and P are three matrices and $P^{\top} = P$

In Kalman filter derivation, the result for this is

$(HP)^{\top}$

(refer to equation 11.24 and 11.25 in [Here](http://web.mit.edu/kirtley/kirtley/binlustuff/literature/control/Kalman%20filter.pdf)).

I am not quite understand it, and why the result is not $HP$. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard some people scorn it but The Matrix Cookbook is full of useful information. For example, in the derivatives of traces section, one can see that

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf X}}\text{Tr}({\bf XA}) = {\bf A}^\text{T}
$$

Note that a trace is a linear operator so it commutes with the derivative. To prove the above relation, you could differentiate ${\bf XA}$ and then take the trace to arrive at the same result.

Comment: Thank you. I will read the book and have a look.

Comment: Just so you know, it's not really a book, just a long list of identities.